# Bounds of weighted sums of Mangoldt function under the Riemann Hypothesis

Tags: nt.number-theory

Hello,

Can anyone help me with the following implication of the GRH which is fundamental while proving the Odd Goldbach's Conjecture?

$$\psi(x,\chi):=\sum_{n\leq x}\Lambda(n)\chi(n)=O(x^{1/2}\log^2 x)$$ where $\chi$ is a non-trivial Dirichlet character.

Also tell me the difference in proof while considering the trivial Dirichlet Character, $\chi$.

Thank You.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "fundamental while proving the Odd Goldbach's Conjecture", since the "conjecture" was proved by Vinogradov without GRH.

Comment: Vinogradov's proof showed that every _sufficiently large_ odd integer can be written as the sum of three primes; concluding this for _every_ odd integer greater than 6 requires GRH (so far).

Comment: @Greg: Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @ GH: by "fundamental while proving the Odd Goldbach's Conjecture", I mean the proof of the vinogradov's theorem when it is proved by assuming the GRH. Of course in the original proof of Vinogradov, he did not use anything of GRH. I was actually stuck with the formulae while studying the proof of it under the GRH.
@Greg: I didn't know actually that extending vinogradov's theorem for every odd numbers requires GRH. Thanks again but I will check that out.  

Answer (score 2):

This can be found, for example, as Theorem 13.7 in Montgomery and Vaughan's *Multiplicative Number Theory I. Classical Theory*.

Comment: That's really helpful. Thanks a lot. 